# `undo-outer-limit` exceeded in Org-agenda buffer

Tags: org-agenda

I'm having this problem when I try to open the TODO items from org-agenda via `C-c a t` or `C-c a n` (where `C-c a` is the keybinding for `org-agenda`), emacs freezes and I get the following Warning message :

```
Warning (undo): Buffer '*Org Agenda*' undo info was 24109632 bytes long. The undo info was discarded
because it exceeded 'undo-outer-limit'. 

This is normal if you executed a command that made a huge change to the buffer. In that case, to 
prevent similar problems in the future, set 'undo-outer-limit' to a value that is large enough to cover 
the maximum size of normal changes you expect a single command to make, but not so large that it might 
exceed the maximum memory allotted to Emacs. 

If you did not execute any such command, the situation is probably due to a bug and you should report it. 

You can disable the popping up of this buffer by adding the entry (undo discard-info) to the user option 
'warning-suppress-types', which is defined in the warnings' library.
```

I have tried increasing this to 100,000,000 bytes (which only changed the number in the above warning to 100245184), and even the unlimited option, but the problem persists. As a last resort I reinstalled emacs from scratch and loaded my config from my .org file, and the problem still remains.

EDIT: Some details added from OP's comment.

It happens when I open the agenda view using `C-c a t` or `C-c a n`. Just now I also tried using a new `.org` file and it works with one or two entries but freezes when I went ahead and put five. And yes, emacs freezes: I can't even highlight the text on screen so I took a screenshot and converted it to text to even get the Warning error message - which also pops up after a few minutes. I close it from the Activity Monitor (since I'm usingMac OS).

Comment: "... when I try to open the TODO items from org-agenda...": can you describe exactly what you do to get that buffer (e.g. "I press RET on a TODO item. The TODO item is in a file that contains N TODO entries and the size of the file is B bytes. The file is marked modified etc etc" - any information you can provide will be helpful). And does emacs really freeze? IOW, you have to kill it afterwards and start a new session?

Comment: @NickD thanks for the comment, its when I open the agenda view using ```C-c a t``` or ```C-c a n```. Just now I also tried using a new .org file and it works with 1-2 entries but freezes when I went ahead and put 5. And yes emacs freezes, I cant even highlight the text on screen so I took a screenshot and converted it to text to even get the Warning error message - which also pops up after a few minutes. I close it from the Activity Monitor (since I'm usingMac OS)

Comment: Thanks for the additional details: I added them to your question (comments can disappear at any time). What happens if you start with `emacs -Q` bypassing your initialization file? Do you still have the problem?

Comment: I just ran emacs via ```emacs -Q``` and linked my agenda files, and that gives no problems

Comment: So the problem is in your init file. If your init file is small, you can read it and try to guess where the problem is. Otherwise, you can use the bisection method to figure out where you introduced the problem: comment out (roughly) half the file and see if the problem is encountered. If it is, then it is in the half you kept, otherwise in the half that you commented out. Lather, rinse repeat: you have to be organized but it's a very fast way to zero in on problems in the init file.